# print chart image as base64 string

Tags: php

I am using a 3rd party library to build a chart. The image is displayed when the following is run `$chart->render();`

This will output the raw image directly. I am trying to print the base64 encoding for this image but i cannot seem to get it to work.

Trying this:

```
$raw = $chart->render();
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($raw);
echo $data;
```

However, the output is still the raw image and not the base64 encoding.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there mate, the one step that you're missing is actually "grabbing" the image. Give this a shot:

```
ob_start();
echo $chart->render();
$raw = ob_get_clean();
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($raw);
echo $data;
```